# ¿Cómo devolver 0 en vez de NULL, si una consulta SQL MySQL no me trae ninguna fila?

Tags: mysql, sql

tengo una consulta SQL en el motor MySQL, la cual necesito que me devuelva los datos que pido, y si no me los encuentra, que me devuelva 0, en vez de vacío o null, ¿cómo lo puedo hacer?

Ésta es la consulta:

```
SELECT detallesservicios.idProfesional 
FROM detallesservicios INNER JOIN servicios 
ON detallesservicios.idServicio = servicios.idServicio 
WHERE servicios.fecha = "2018-12-25"
  AND NOT(timediff(servicios.hora, '09:00:00') > '00:59:00') 
GROUP BY idProfesional
```

Bien, esta consulta lo que hace es comprobar que un profesional en la fecha especificada tenga un servicio por hacer y que ademas la hora especificada para un posible nuevo servicio sea menor a 00:59:00 del trabajo que ya tenga programado, supongamos que en navidad ya tiene un trabajo a las 09:00:00, y yo le quiero asignar otro servicio en la misma fecha y en la misma hora; ahi me tendría que devolver el idProfesional (porque se encuentra ocupado en esa fecha y hora).

El problema surge porque los ID's que me devuelva esta consulta yo luego hago otro `INNER JOIN` en el cual la clausula `ON` en vez de tener `=` la tengo `<>`, y si la consulta de arriba no me devuelve nada (es decir, que no hay ningún profesional con un servicio en esa fecha y en una hora de diferencia con la hora especificada) no me trae nada aunque estén disponibles todos los profesionales.

Si no me entendieron la explicación va una más fácil:

Necesito que ésta consulta, si encuentra algún ID me los devuelva, y sino, en vez de no devolver nada, me devuelva 0, porque luego necesito este cero para comparar en otro `INNER JOIN` porque no puedo comparar un numero con algo vacío o `NULL`, probé con el `IF(COUNT(*)=0, 0, detallesservicios.idProfesional)` dentro del `SELECT` pero cuando se cumple la condición no me devuelve el valor que tendría que devolver cuando la condición se cumpliera.

Ésta sería la consulta un poco más completa:

```
SELECT PH.idProfesional 
FROM (SELECT P.idProfesional 
      FROM horarios 
      INNER JOIN (SELECT idProfesional 
                  FROM profesionales 
                  WHERE idOficio = 1 AND idEstadoP = 1 
                  GROUP BY idProfesional) AS P
      ON P.idProfesional = horarios.idProfesional 
      WHERE idDia = 2 
      AND desde < '09:00:00' 
      AND '09:00:00' < hasta 
      AND idArea = 1 
      GROUP BY P.idProfesional) AS PH
INNER JOIN (SELECT detallesservicios.idProfesional 
            FROM detallesservicios 
            INNER JOIN servicios 
            ON detallesservicios.idServicio = servicios.idServicio 
            WHERE servicios.fecha = "2019-12-25" 
            AND NOT(TIMEDIFF(servicios.hora, '09:00:00') > '00:59:00') 
            GROUP BY idProfesional) AS S
ON PH.idProfesional <> S.idProfesional
```

cómo pueden ver me está dando un conflicto el último `ON` ya que no puedo comparar varios `INTEGER` con algo `NULL`

Comment: por lo que entiendo es una subconsulta no? pon la otra consulta donde usas esta

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Si tu query solamente regresa una columna (detallesservicios.idProfesional). Fácilmente puedes hacer UNION como el siguiente código:

```
(SELECT detallesservicios.idProfesional 
FROM detallesservicios INNER JOIN servicios 
ON detallesservicios.idServicio = servicios.idServicio 
WHERE servicios.fecha = "2018-12-25" AND NOT(timediff(servicios.hora, '09:00:00') > '00:59:00') 
GROUP BY idProfesional)
UNION
(SELECT 0) LIMIT 1;
```

Nota el `LIMIT` al final, es importante, ya que si encuentra un resultado para tu consulta, este query regresaría dos filas, el id que encontró y 0. Con limit 1 te aseguras de que solo venga el resultado que encontró en caso de que si se haya encontrado.

Comment: O bien podrías omitir el LIMIT 1 del final pero debes saber que siempre va a haber un resultado 0 en la última fila.

Comment: ¡Muchas gracias a todos por su tiempo! Al parecer ésta es la solución, la estaré testeando bien y luego la marco como respuesta. Gracias @OrlandoMartinez

Comment: Pregunta Orlando, ¿Si la consulta de arriba puede devolverme uno o mas id's, como hago con el LIMIT 1 para que si no me regresa nada, me devuelva 0 y si me devuelve uno o mas id me devuelva esos uno o mas id?

Comment: Qué tal GADGustavo67, hasta donde yo se, no es posible hacer lo que pides con una consulta simple. Podrías hacerlo encapsulando la consulta en una función, dentro de dicha función verificar si la consulta no devolvió ningún resultado retorna 0 en otro caso retorna los resultados de la consulta. Otra opción es quitar el 'LIMIT 1' a la consulta, y del lado del 'cliente' es decir, tu lenguaje de programación utilizar N - 1 filas del resultado donde N es el total de filas que retornó la consulta.

Answer (score 3):

Puedes usar el IFNULL:

```
SELECT IFNULL(detallesservicios.idProfesional,0)
FROM detallesservicios INNER JOIN servicios 
ON detallesservicios.idServicio = servicios.idServicio 
WHERE servicios.fecha = "2018-12-25" AND NOT(timediff(servicios.hora, '09:00:00') > '00:59:00') 
GROUP BY idProfesional
```

Comment: No, en vez de cero devuelve NULL, pero cuando vienen datos devuelve los datos. Sigue el problema.

Answer (score 1):

Lo que ocupas es una sentencia CASE, la cual quedaría de la siguiente manera:

```
SELECT CASE
       WHEN detallesservicios.idProfesional IS NULL THEN 0
       ELSE detallesservicios.idProfesional
       END AS idProfesional
FROM detallesservicios INNER JOIN servicios 
ON detallesservicios.idServicio = servicios.idServicio 
WHERE servicios.fecha = "2018-12-25" AND NOT(timediff(servicios.hora, '09:00:00') > '00:59:00') 
GROUP BY idProfesional
```

Para mayor información:

> https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_case.asp

Comment: No, en vez de cero devuelve NULL, pero cuando vienen datos devuelve los datos. Sigue el problema.