# ¿Cómo obtener valores de una tabla/consulta que sean diferentes de otra?

Tags: mysql, sql

supongamos este ejemplo:

Tengo una tabla con todos los profesionales que realizan trabajos (`T1`), y tengo otra con los `ID` de los profesionales que NO ESTÁN disponibles (`T2`), necesito obtener los `ID` de los profesionales que están disponibles, es decir, todos los de `T1` que son distintos de los que están en `T2`

Probé con:

```
SELECT T1.ID FROM T1 INNER JOIN T2 ON T1.ID <> T2.ID
```

Pero no funciona, trae todos los datos y los que no estan en T2 los trae repetidos. ¿Cómo puedo hacerlo?.

PD: Ésta pregunta surgió porque todos iba bien con [ésta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/201729/c%C3%B3mo-devolver-0-en-vez-de-null-si-una-consulta-sql-mysql-no-me-trae-ninguna-fi/201749#201749) , pero cuando devuelve mas de un profesional que ya tiene un servicio a esa fecha y hora, solo me devuelve un `ID`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podrías probar con la función EXISTS, algo así:

```
SELECT T1.ID
FROM T1
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM T2 WHERE T2.ID = T1.ID)
```

¡Suerte!

Comment: ¿Qué función cumple el SELECT 1?

Comment: Es lo mismo que si pusiéramos SELECT * o cualquier campo de la tabla, el EXISTS sólo verifica que la consulta encuentre un registro.